# Input setting using Registers

Tags: embedded, register-allocation

I have a simple c program for printing n Fibonacci numbers and I would like to compile it to ELF object file. Instead of setting the number of fibonacci numbers (n) directly in my c code, I would like to set them in the registers since I am simulating it for an ARM processor.How can I do that?

Here is the code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ITERATIONS 3

static float fib(float i) {
    return (i>1) ? fib(i-1) + fib(i-2) : i;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    float i;
    printf("starting...\n");

    for(i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++) {
    printf("fib(%f) = %f\n", i, fib(i));
    }

    printf("finishing...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to set the ITERATIONS counter in my Registers rather than in the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What registers?  Does that correspond to anything in the program?

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence is an *positive integer sequence*, `float` is probably an inappropriate type to use in this case.  It will not accurately represent values with more than 6 significant decimal digits. `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` would be better choices, and more efficiently calculated by an ARM without an FPU.

Comment: @Clifford* If he needs larger numbers, he can use *double*, and calculate using a closed form solution.

Comment: @Jay: That *would* give a larger range, but is still not precise for >15 digits.  If you calculate a Fibonacci number imprecisely, it not really a Fibonacci number.  A `uint64_t` or a 64bit `unsigned long long` will be good for 19 digits (log10(pow(2,64)).

Comment: @Raja -- I have the feeling that I am missing the point of your question -- you do not seem to be interested in the most efficient way to generate Fibonacci numbers, it seems you are more interested in how to direct the "C" compiler (and linker) to make the most efficient use of registers it can. Is this correct?

Comment: @JayElston: Yes, I would like to check the register input setting. Code doesnt matter really much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***register*** keyword can be used to suggest to the compiler that it uses a registers for the iterator and the number of iterations:

```
register float i;
register int numIterations = ITERATIONS;
```

but that will not help much. First of all, the compiler may or may not use your suggestion. Next, values will still need to be placed on the stack for the call to *fib()*, and, finally, depending on what functions you call within your loop, code in the procedure are calling could save your register contents in the stack frame at procedure entry, and restore them as part of the code implementing the procedure return.

If you really need to make every instruction count, then you will need to write machine code (using an assembly language). That way, you have direct control over your register usage. Assembly language programming is not for the faint of heart. Assembly language development is several times slower than using higher level languages, your risk of inserting bugs is greater, and they are much more difficult to track down. High level languages were developed for a reason, and the C language was developed to help write Unix. The minicomputers that ran the first Unix systems were extremely slow, but the reason C was used instead of assembly was that even then, it was more important to have code that took less time to code, had fewer bugs, and was easier to debug than assembler.

If you want to try this, [here are the answers to a previous question on stackoverflow about resources for ARM programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270078/resources-for-learning-arm-assembly) that might be helpful.

One tactic you might take is to isolate your performance-critical code into a procedure, write the procedure in C, the capture the generated assembly language representation. Then rewrite the assembler to be more efficient. Test thoroughly, and get at least one other set of eyeballs to look the resulting code over.

Good Luck!

Comment: I assume that he simply wants to modify the iteration count at runtime within the simulator.  That does not require a register, simply a variable.  Moreover the `register` qualifier will be ignored by most compilers and certainly does not specify any specific register.  In the ARM ABI, the first four arguments of a function are passed in R0-R3 (unless `double` or `long long`), and further arguments are stacked.

Comment: I did say _suggest to he compiler_ rather than _direct the compiler to_ use a register for the variable.

Comment: Thanks for that. But I don't need more than 150 fibonacci numbers. As mentioned in the other comment, I have just taken the fibonacci example to check how can the number count be passed to the register instead of declaring it in the code itself. I am validating the timing results of both the approaches 1) Passing it in the code by declaring the variable and assigning a value to it and 2) Declaring the number counter variable in the code and assigning a value to it at compile time in the registers. The result or the output of the program is of little importance. its rather the timing.

Comment: @Raga: You are sweating the small stuff.  Efficient loop code is the job of the compiler, your analysis is going to take far more time that any saving will achieve probably in the lifetime of the product! If you are measuring performance, you should not use `printf` within the loop, the loop will probably spend 95% of its time in `printf` where most of the code is.  Instead store the results in an array, and print them after or observe them in your debugger.  Even then and minute saving in the termination test will be insignificant compared to the time spent in the `fib()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Make ITERATIONS a variable rather than a literal constant, then you can set its value directly in your debugger/simulator's watch or locals window just before the loop executes.

Alternatively as it appears you have stdio support, why not just accept the value via console input?

Comment: I can make ITERATIONS a variable. This example is just to demonstrate the working of the simulator Im working with. The real program I simulate is more complex and purely embedded. So using a console input doesn't help. I am actually simulating 2 configurations of the same program 1)setting the input through registers and 2)Setting the input by changing the code. I am using OVP Simulator for ARM7 processor. What did u mean by debuggers windows. Im using Msys development environment to run the simulator

Comment: I am not familiar with OVP, but most simulators support debugging via a source level debugger such as GDB or Insight.  In such a debugger you can view and modify modify the executing applications variables directly.  If you do not have the means to perform such debugging both in simulation and on real hardware, you are hardly equipped for defective development, and I question the benefit of simulation in the first place.

Comment: ... I have just taken a look at the OVP site, and watced a video of an application running on OVP using Eclipse and GDB, so it can be done.